# Margins not takign effect if value greater than container boundary

Tags: android, android-layout

If we set bottom margin to a value greater than the container height, the margin does not have any effect. I want the view to go away whenever bottom/top margin > height or right/left margin > width. I am trying to achieve anchoring effect, all works fine if margin is within container width/height. let me know if any one has nay ideas on this.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the view to go away whenever bottom/top margin > height or right/left margin > width.

Don't set the margins that way. If you want "the view to go away", use `setVisibility()`, please.

A `View`, margins and all, cannot be larger than its container.

Comment: I have no control over what the margin will be.The views are created dynamically .If a view is anchored to the bottom ,with bot margin of say 400 in portrait mode,in landscape mode I want the bottom margin to be still 400 and result in the view being squeezed. Also the container size can also be changed dynamically, thus the anchoring effect can be seen without orientation change.  I have no control over how large the container will be, the anchor flags, the view size nor the margins of the view. Like I said I am getting my desired result, except when the container is smaller than the margin

Comment: @Veeresh: **YOU** are the one setting the margins. They are not spontaneously being set by a magic wand. **YOU** are the one changing the container size. The size is not being changed by mystical forces. All of that is happening by Java code somewhere. Hence, **YOU** are perfectly capable of determining when you want the view to not appear based upon these values, and **YOU** are perfectly capable of calling `setVisibility()` as needed to achieve the visibility results you seek.

Comment: Let me rephrase. I am trying to make sure the bot margin is not greater than the container, one approach I am trying is by overriding the measureChildWithMargins() method of view group, this is not taking effect. When a container is redrawn, where do I intercept and change the child layout params so that the margins do not exceed containers final width and height?

Comment: @Veeresh: Ah. Good question. I have not created a `ViewGroup` from scratch, and so I cannot answer that. I would recommend you open up a fresh StackOverflow question that asks about this specifically. My apologies.